# How to Rankx and reset count where yyyymm Date gaps exist

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

How can I add a condition to the below dax to identify the gap between 202209 and 202305 and reset the count?

```html
-- Calc Column
Active_records = 
var _GP = Table[GP]
var indv_id = Table[ID]
var _end_date = Table[DATE]
var _DATE = EOMONTH(_end_date,-24)+1

VAR _COUNT = RANKX ( 
        FILTER (ALL(Table),
            Table[GP] = EARLIER(Table[GP])
            && Table[ID] = EARLIER(Table[ID])
            && Table[MALES_UNDER_35] = EARLIER(Table[MALES_UNDER_35])
            && Table[DATE] >= _DATE
            && Table[DATE] <= _end_date
        ),        
        Table[DATE],
        ,
        ASC,
        Dense
    )
 RETURN 
 
_COUNT
```

[image]

ended up adding to my sql instead of PBI.
[Reset DENSE_RANK() OVER partition by where just one row is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77001515/reset-dense-rank-over-partition-by-where-just-one-row-is-different/77002287#77002287)